# Need to fix this: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF

Tags: java, eof, jbpm

I'm trying to access the uniprot website to retrieve a list of protein sequences with their profiles as an XML file. The file size is huge. I'm using the eclipse that come with JBPM full package. Also, I'm using ubuntu under virtual box. Now when I run my code I'm getting this stacktrace:

```
 java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.fastRead(ChunkedInputStream.java:234)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:662)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2512)
    at edu.uga.uniprot.amna.QueryExecuter.ExecuteQuery(QueryExecuter.java:40)
    at edu.uga.uniprot.amna.Uniprot.getProteenStringByDFamily(Uniprot.java:40)
    at edu.uga.uniprot.amna.Uniprot.getProteensByDFamily(Uniprot.java:55)
    at org.drools.bpmn2.Process_org_drools_bpmn2_Hello_World_0.action4(Process_org_drools_bpmn2_Hello_World_0.java:60)
    at org.drools.bpmn2.Process_org_drools_bpmn2_Hello_World_0Action4Invoker.execute(Process_org_drools_bpmn2_Hello_World_0Action4Invoker.java:14)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.ActionNodeInstance.internalTrigger(ActionNodeInstance.java:47)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:122)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerConnection(NodeInstanceImpl.java:185)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:150)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StartNodeInstance.java:49)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.internalTrigger(StartNodeInstance.java:41)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:122)
    at org.jbpm.ruleflow.instance.RuleFlowProcessInstance.internalStart(RuleFlowProcessInstance.java:35)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.impl.ProcessInstanceImpl.start(ProcessInstanceImpl.java:188)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.start(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:302)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:154)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:124)
    at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.startProcess(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:1095)
    at org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.startProcess(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:306)
    at com.sample.ProcessTest.main(ProcessTest.java:49)
java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to execute Action
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.ActionNodeInstance.internalTrigger(ActionNodeInstance.java:49)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:122)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerConnection(NodeInstanceImpl.java:185)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:150)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StartNodeInstance.java:49)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.internalTrigger(StartNodeInstance.java:41)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:122)
    at org.jbpm.ruleflow.instance.RuleFlowProcessInstance.internalStart(RuleFlowProcessInstance.java:35)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.impl.ProcessInstanceImpl.start(ProcessInstanceImpl.java:188)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.start(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:302)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:154)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:124)
    at org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.startProcess(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:1095)
    at org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.startProcess(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:306)
    at com.sample.ProcessTest.main(ProcessTest.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:33)
    at edu.uga.uniprot.amna.Uniprot.loadProteenFromString(Uniprot.java:117)
    at edu.uga.uniprot.amna.Uniprot.getProteensByDFamily(Uniprot.java:58)
    at org.drools.bpmn2.Process_org_drools_bpmn2_Hello_World_0.action4(Process_org_drools_bpmn2_Hello_World_0.java:60)
    at org.drools.bpmn2.Process_org_drools_bpmn2_Hello_World_0Action4Invoker.execute(Process_org_drools_bpmn2_Hello_World_0Action4Invoker.java:14)
    at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.ActionNodeInstance.internalTrigger(ActionNodeInstance.java:47)
    ... 14 more
```

can any one help how to resolve this error OR what cause's it?

Here is the code that generates the error:

```
public static String ExecuteQuery(String queryURL, boolean writeFile) { 

    URL url;

    try {

        System.out.println("Strat getting Data"); 

        String output = ""; 

        int read; 

        RandomAccessFile  file = null; 

        url = new URL(queryURL);

        HttpURLConnection connection =

                (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();



        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        connection.connect();       



        //read the result from the server

        if(writeFile == true) { 

            file = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");

        } 

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));



        while((read = stream.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) { 

            //System.out.println(new String(buffer)); 

            output = output + new String(buffer).substring(0, read); 

            if(writeFile == true) { 

                file.write(buffer, 0, read); 

            } 

            buffer = new byte[1024]; 

        }

        System.out.println(output); 

        return output; 

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    } 

    return null; 

}
```

Comment: How about some of the Java codes???

Comment: You don't need to allocate a new buffer every time around that loop, that's just flogging the GC to death. You could beneficially rewrite `new String(buffer).substring(0, read)` as `new String(buffer, 0, read)` too.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I finally resolved the problem which seems to be happened because of the fast read with slow connection. once I've added a `System.out.println(new String(buffer))` it works fine.

The `println` statement **slow down the read operation** and make it compatible with the connection speed.

I wish this be helpful to anyone face the same problem.

Comment: Unconvincing explanation. Your reading code can't run any faster than the data arrives: it blocks while there is no data.

Comment: EJP I've posted this question and no one gave one reasonable solution because the error "premature EOF" weird. So, if u can't believe this solution please let me know how would u resolve the problem, the code is already posted so, go ahead and run it.

Comment: I didn't say I knew the solution, I said that your explanation is unconvincing. In other words you don't know the solution either yet. You haven't solved the problem: you've just moved it, or deferred it.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by you passing a null value into new StringReader() on line 117 of Uniprot.java.

You can see this by your stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:33)
    at edu.uga.uniprot.amna.Uniprot.loadProteenFromString(Uniprot.java:117)
    at edu.uga.uniprot.amna.Uniprot.getProteensByDFamily(Uniprot.java:58)
```

The constructor for StringReader is the following:

```
public StringReader(String   s) {
    this.str = s;
    this.length = s.length(); // line 33
}
```

See more [StringReader](http://kickjava.com/src/java/io/StringReader.java.htm).

Comment: Thanks for responding buddy, but I'm asking about the java.io.IOException: Premature EOF which causes the null value later.

Comment: Is this one exception, or two exceptions? If it's two, then you need to post your code so that we can see it. edu.uga.uniprot.amna.QueryExecuter.ExecuteQuery preferably

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to download a lot of uniprot entries in one http connection you might have your http connection die on you. I suggest that you have a look at http://www.uniprot.org/faq/28#retrieving_entries_via_queries and use the offset and limit parameters on your http request to limit the number of entries you try to retrieve in one go.

Dynamic http request tend to fail when downloading very large result sets. The other option is to download all entries via ftp and work on the download file. See the [UniProt FTP site](ftp://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/current_release/knowledgebase)